# How to best populate points within a polygon with a set of rules

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I've got a polygon (a Circle) with a certain size. I want to put points inside it, as much as I can, but with a set of rules :

1. Points can't be near each other, up to 500 meters.
2. Points can't be near a polyline (roads) up to 200 meters.

Any idea how can I do it with ArcMap or Qgis ?

Comment: You will end up with the triangular grid with sides being 500m. Then you can erase points within the 200m buffer zone around the polylines...

Comment: Thanks, I just used the Repeating shapes plugin, worked amazingly!